# Disable request verification token in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC seems to inject a request verification token in all of my forms:

```html
<form class="actions" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yes">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/some/url">No</a>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="...">
</form>
```

I'm handling CSRF in Ajax and don't want this extra `input` element in all of my forms. Any way to disable it?

The element is added even without a call to `AddAntiforgery` in `Startup.cs`. I'm running on ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antiforgery middleware is added to the Dependency injection container when one of the following APIs is called in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
AddMvc
MapRazorPages
MapControllerRoute
MapBlazorHub
```

Details please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration)

To disable it, try below IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute

```
[Authorize]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomethingSafe(SomeViewModel model)
    {
        // no antiforgery token required
    }
}
```

Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#override-global-or-controller-antiforgery-attributes)

Comment: That explains it. And thank you for the link to the prevent CSRF document. I would have wished for a global way to disable this. Adding asp-antiforgery, !, or removeTagHelper will be the solution for now, but requires extra markup on a lot of forms. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The token is appended by the [Form Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-form-tag-helper). If you don't need the other features of the Tag Helper, it can be removed using `@removeTagHelper` (in view or globally by adding to `_ViewImports.cshtml`):

```
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

See [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration) for further details/options.

Answer (score 0):

Just idea I would make reference to that  `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` can be used to **disable** the global `[AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on certain actions if needed.

```
public class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but adding the `IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` doesn't result in the token not being generated automatically in all form posts without an action.

Comment: You need to set the Order property to make it run before the ValidateAntiforgeryToken  ex 
new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute() { Order = 1001  }